# How to set up Google Places API in Google Developer Console?

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api

I plan to use Google Places API autocompletion in my iOS app, so I have set up a Google Places API in Google Developers Console. But when I am sending HTTP request, I get a refuse message back. Any idea what I am missing?

- You can see Google Places API is enabled

[image]

- I sent some request, it is on the chart

[image]

- But request were refused

[image]

Meantime I have set up billing info.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found some hints: [Google Places API Autocomplete on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520177/google-places-api-autocomplete-on-ios)

Need to create `Browser key`, leave empty `HTTP refers`. Use browser key in URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Client ID with "Installed Application" and select iOS in side the [Developer Console](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?sacu=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fapps%2Fpublish%2F&hl=en&service=androiddeveloper)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using an iOS key. Please verify with the following steps that you are getting the correct key.

- Visit [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) by entering your Google Credentials.
- Create a project or choose an existing one.
- In the left column select APIs, In the Google Maps API section select Places API. And Click the enable API button so that it is enabled. The autocomplete API and the Places API share the same Key
- In the left column select `Credentials` and click `Create new Key`.
- In the dialog box select iOS key, It will create a iOS key in form of string. Use this Key in your request.

Hope this Helps!!!